# Why does this exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, collections

So how is it possible that

```
@article.authors.exists?
```

is true, and

```
@article.authors.empty?
```

is also true????

the context is a new action:

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
  # @article.build.authors unless @article.authors.exists?
  # @article.build.authors if @article.authors.empty?
end
```

and

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authors
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors
end
```

Comment: Is it possible that you've removed all of the authors from the `@article` object, but have not committed your changes to the database (so `exists?` still returns `true`)? You don't provide any context for this result.

Comment: I've recreated your code, and under this condition I get `@article.authors.exists?` returning `false` and `@article.authors.empty?` returning `true`, both as expected.

Comment: That's very odd, i am in the debugger now, and it says:
@article.authors => [], @article.authors.exists? => true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, think I have solved it, because @article has not been saved yet,

@article.authors.exists?

runs the sql:

```
[1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 FROM `authors` WHERE `authors `.`type` IN ('professional') AND `authors `.`article_id` IS NULL LIMIT 1[0m
```

So it returns whether there are any authors without an article.

Answer (score 4):

*This is not the answer you are looking for - I misread the question. I think Jeremy had it right in his comment above.*

Because in Ruby anything that is non-nil and not explicitly `false` evaluates to `true` in boolean comparisons, even `0`. `@article.authors`, in this case, is an empty array, or `[]`. `[]` is not nil, and it is not `false`, therefore it is evaluated as `true` in a boolean comparison. The `empty?` method on the array object returns true if the array is empty, or `[]`, which in this case it is.

Here's some broader information about this: http://railsclub.com/2011/03/the-difference-between-nil-true-false-blank-and-empty/

Comment: I don't think this is it. `exists?` is a function in ActiveRecord which queries the database to see if a row can be found, and returns a boolean. It does not simply evaluate the array in a boolean context.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb

Comment: Sorry, I must've misread the question, thought it was just "how is it possible that @article.authors" is true and missed the "exists?" method in the chain.